# Change Orientation from background in android

Tags: android, background, orientation

I have this requirement  where i am  suppose  to  change the  orientation of the  display after a certain  number of  ticks ,  this  may well  happen  even  when  **my app  is not in foreground.**

How  do i  do this ??

I looked  around a  bit and  found  WindowManagerService.java has a "setRotation" API

I rooted  my app  but  even now i  dont see any  change in oreintation even on home screen..   please any  help

this is  how i m  calling the  API.

```
private IWindowManager iwm; 
iwm = IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("window"));
iwm.setRotation(orent,true,0)
```

please note the value of "orent" is  cycled  from 0 to 3   (1st  time  called with 0 then, 1 then 2 ....) still i never  see any  change in orientation ..
Is  there  some non  technical  issue  like  settings  etc   or  I m  not the  proper  API's ? Im  using  Froyo  codebase

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to change the UI of an activity if it is not in the foreground.  If the orientation changes are time based, it should be easy to calculate which orientation your activity should be in when it returns to the foreground.  Just add some logic in `onResume` and load the correct layout then.

Comment: well actually  it  does  in my  case  ..i happen  to  remotely control my  phone (s) with  this  app  also  ticks is just one of the trigger  factor and hence i  cant  rely on  just timer  logic in  "onResume " ..isnt  there a  way to do this ?